# Modify the recipient(s) context menu in Outlook 2010's MailItem?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

If you open a email you've received and right-click the sender or a recipient, a context menu appears with short list of buttons (cut, copy, ... Add to Outlook Contacts, Look Up Outlook Contacts, Contact Card).  I would like to add my own custom button to this context menu.  Unfortunately,  I cannot find the control identifier (msoID) for the context menu.  I've looked in the list of [control identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627) for read mail items but can find nothing that resembles the context menu or any of it's buttons. Is this context menu not available for modification? I suspect I'm looking in the wrong place.  Any help is much appreciated.

The complete (or perhaps not so complete) list of Control Identifiers is found here: [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627)

Answer (score 0):

I found it in this MSDN post: [Customizing the Context Menu of a Contact Card in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909466.aspx)

the name of the msoID is `ContextMenuContactCardRecipient`.  You will also see an identical context menu on a button on the contact card itself.  The msoID for this secondary context menu is `ContextMenuContactCardOverflowDropdown`.  I'm completely stumped as to why MS did not include this in its list of control identifiers.  I'm still looking for the control IDs for items on these context menus.

Comment: How did you find "ContextMenuContactCardOverflowDropdown"? It is not listed at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers as expected. Outlook 2019 has replaced the secondary context menu and introduced yet another undocumented context menu control, and I need to find its idMso.